# Unable to get json data from rest api in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

code:

```
<?php
    $url = base_url()."eventapi";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
?>
```

eventapi controller

```
<?php
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
class Eventapi extends REST_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    function index_get()
    {
        $data['client_id'] = $this->session->userdata('client_id');
        $client_id = $data['client_id'][0]['client_id'];
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('event');
        $this->db->where('client_id',$client_id);
        $sql = $this->db->get();
        $result = $sql->result_array();
        $this->response($result, 200);
    }
}
```

output:

```
array(0) { }
```

eventapi data

```
[{"id":"1","client_id":"20190702082406","event_type":"Private Event","event_name":"Birthday Celebration","event_date":"2019-08-15","event_time":"08:00 PM","event_des":"Birthday celebration ","s_date":"2019"}]
```

I am creating a simple rest API using Codeigniter where API works fine. Now, the problem is that when I am getting data from `eventapi` using `curl` it shows me output i.e `array(0) { }` I don't know why? So, How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `eventapi` is the controller function? if yes share the code of `eventapi `

Comment: check @VinayPatil

Comment: have you checked the query? is that returning correct data?

Comment: Also, check the `$client_id` value, if it is undefined then it will result in the empty data from the query

Comment: yes, I check and its return correct data @VinayPatil

Comment: did you face any `session` related error? Are you getting `$client_id` from session ?

Comment: yes, I am getting `$client_id` from session @M.Hemant

Comment: did you check and echo `$this->db->last_query()`?

Comment: Yes, @M.Hemant I had already check `last_query()` and it's working fine

Comment: is it working via curl?

Comment: No, @M.Hemant it's not working with `curl` or `file_get_contents`

Comment: so now tell Are you getting `$client_id` from a session ?

Comment: Yes, Sir @M.Hemant

Comment: Did you check why your `$this->db->last_query()` is not working via `curl`?

Comment: Sir, I already told you `last_query` is also working @M.Hemant

Answer (score 0):

If the above one is your code, you didn't add any parameters. The array passing with empty input. So you get empty output. Please correct the input.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $inputParameters");

Please add these lines along with the curl .

And don't forget to add the header also .
//set the content type to application/json

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

//return response instead of outputting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);